# Mysql bind_param php issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have sql query

```
$query = "select * from users where username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."'";
```

How to use mysql bind_param in this query

Trying this link and don't know how to give two conditions in where.

> http://www.ultramegatech.com/2009/07/using-mysql-prepared-statements-in-php/

Comment: `binding parameters` are not supported by `mysql` you need to use either `mysqli` , `pdo` etc...

Comment: pls suggest me for mysqli

Comment: @user3350099 the link you posted in your question refers the same.. you dont need any other suggestion.. just follow it... its for mysqli..

Comment: it is working fine but when i am giving two conditions in where it is not working.$stmt->prepare("SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username=? && password = ?")

Comment: how does your bind_param() function look?

Comment: $stmt->bind_param('ss',$username,$password);

Comment: any error message with: `if (!$stmt->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=? && password = ?")) { echo $stmt->error; }`